# Encode Images at URL in PHP Array as Base64

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

This is the code I have and I am trying to get and encode the image contents as base64 but I keep ending up with the URL as a base64 string.

In the end I get images as an array from a API I need to transcode them to Base64 to store in a local DB.

This is based on the Gravity Forms API, Wordpress, PHP, mySQL, (LAMP) etc.

```
<?php
$images = array();
    $body = array();
    $imagesDecoded = array();
    $imgUrls = array(
                    '1' => 'bg.jpg',
                    '2' => 'meeting.jpg',
                    '3' => 'testimonial.jpg',
                    '4' => 'works.jpg',
                );

$imgUrls = array_map(function($el) {
    return 'http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/' . $el;
}, $imgUrls);

print'<pre>';
print_r($imgUrls);
print'</pre>';

foreach ($imgUrls as $image) {
    $data = file_get_contents($imgUrls);
    $data = base64_encode($imgUrls);
    array_push($body, $data);

}

print '<pre>';
print_r ($body);
print '<pre>';

foreach ($body as $bodyimage) {
    $dataDec = base64_decode($bodyimage);
    array_push($imagesDecoded, $dataDec);
}
print '<pre>';
print_r ($imagesDecoded);
print '<pre>';
```

This is the output from when I run this code now:

```
Array
(
    [ptSignature] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/bg.jpg
    [pSignature] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/meeting.jpg
    [witness1Signature] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/testimonial.jpg
    [witness2Signature] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/works.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => aHR0cDovL29ybGFuZG9qb2VzLmNvLnVrL3JpbW9zL2ltYWdlcy9iZy5qcGc=
    [1] => aHR0cDovL29ybGFuZG9qb2VzLmNvLnVrL3JpbW9zL2ltYWdlcy9tZWV0aW5nLmpwZw==
    [2] => aHR0cDovL29ybGFuZG9qb2VzLmNvLnVrL3JpbW9zL2ltYWdlcy90ZXN0aW1vbmlhbC5qcGc=
    [3] => aHR0cDovL29ybGFuZG9qb2VzLmNvLnVrL3JpbW9zL2ltYWdlcy93b3Jrcy5qcGc=
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/bg.jpg
    [1] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/meeting.jpg
    [2] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/testimonial.jpg
    [3] => http://orlandojoes.co.uk/rimos/images/works.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code.

```
$data = file_get_contents($imgUrls); // This is an array of URLs
$data = base64_encode($imgUrls); // You encode the URLs here!
```

Should be:

```
$data = file_get_contents($image); // $image instead of $imgUrls
$data = base64_encode($data); // $data instead of $imgUrls
```

Or simply:

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
```

Side note, you don't need `array_push()` in your code, it's typically only needed if you want to push more than one item at one time. So, you can change it to just:

```
$body[] = $data;
```